# Why are inline block elements misaligned?

Tags: html, css

[image: Problem]

Inside a `div` with `vertical-align: top;` I have two elements, an `img` and a `span` (with aaa inside).

Both elements have `display: inline-block;` and `width` and `height` set.

No matter what I do and what I try, the elements are **MISALIGNED** as shown on picture below.
What is wrong and how can I fix this?

This problem occurs in every browser - FF, IE, Safari ...
http://jsfiddle.net/CaU59/

Comment: Why not put it into jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align` to the elements themselves, not their container.  They are currently aligned `baseline` as you can see from the text lining up with the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/CaU59/2/

Comment: Yes, that was the problem!

Answer (score 11):

`vertical-align: top` is to be added to each element

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/CaU59/1/

Comment: This thing was driving me crazy, that fixed it.