# Vertical align a button in an absolute positioned div

Tags: position, vertical-alignment, absolute

Usually I vertically center a button, inside an absolute positioned div with `top:50%`, and `margin-left:-(height/2)`, but today I realised it's not perfect, or I don't know how to use it correctly.

For example I did 2 examples. In the first example the `<a>` tag is an inline element, in the second example it's a `block` element. The positioning with `block` element is perfect, but unfortunately the width is 100%.

Please explain that why is the second example works well, with `display:block;`?

I'm really interested in your cross browser solution. How do you do this simple stuff?

Here is my css:

```
.container {
    height:240px;
    position:relative;
}

.box {
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background:yellow;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
}

#example2 { left: 250px; }

.btn {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 12px;
    line-height:34px;
    color:#fff;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-17px;
}

#example2 .btn { display:block; }
```

..and html

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="example1" class="box">
        <a href="" class="btn">button</a>
    </div>
    <div id="example2" class="box">
        <a href="" class="btn">button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The online version is available at http://jsfiddle.net/79hqgabq/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alignment issue you see is being caused by the `margin-top: -17px` line as seen by this updated fiddle with that line removed on the `.btn` class: [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79hqgabq/3/)

On another note, vertical alignment is notoriously problematic with old CSS selectors, and it would be a good idea to transition over to [Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) unless you needed to support older browsers.

Here's your problem with the new `display: flex` selector and corresponding sub-selectors: [Demo w/ Flexbox](http://jsfiddle.net/79hqgabq/5/). This removes the emphasis on having to pixel fudge to get proper vertical alignment.

New `.box` class

```
.box {
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background:yellow;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    /* New lines for alignment */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

New `.btn` class (just removed the old tags)

```
.btn {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 12px;
    line-height:34px;
    color:#fff;
    background:red;
}
```

**EDIT:** After researching block elements have the property to expand to 100% of the parent container. This can be explained in more detail [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/). This is why `display:block` div expands until it reaches the padding on the `.box` class.

To answer why the `display: inline-block` element is slightly misaligned is because by default it is aligned on the `baseline`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799503/why-are-inline-block-elements-misaligned) for reference. Changing the vertical alignment of the div to be `vertical-align: top` will fix this.

Here is the new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79hqgabq/6/) that uses all your previous syntax just with the added `vertical-align: middle` property.

Comment: Thank you, it works, but why is it good in my version when I use display:block? In the display:flex version why is the button with display:block not 100% wide? I have to support the older browsers, so this flex version should wait.

Comment: I'll look into it and get back to you - still haven't figured out the perfect response

Comment: Thank you! I'm really interested in it. I also would like to know what is the cross browser best practice for this.